# Get GIT HEAD remote

Tags: git, github

I'm kinda new to Git and I have to compare the HEAD from a lokal branch with a remote branch.

On the lokal branch I get the HEAD with the following command:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD

root@debian:xxxx# git rev-parse --short HEAD
469xxx
```

But how can I get the short HEAD of a remote branch?
For Example:

```
https://github.com/openssl/openssl
```

The lastest short HEAD is there "cded951"

In my case, getting the HEAD and comparing it does it.

```
If local HEAD != remote HEAD do xyz
```

For this check I need the remote HEAD of my github branch.

best regards :)

Solution:

```
git remote update
if ! git diff --quiet origin/master; then
    echo "the branch is different!"
else
    echo "the branch is equal!"
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried `git diff local_branch origin/remote_branch`?

Comment: git only operates on local repositories.  If you want information about a remote branch, first clone the repository, then use `git rev-parse` normally.

Comment: (Note that for repositories hosted on github specifically, you may be able to use the [github api](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to get that information)

Comment: Oh, it's a branch for a "remote *repository*", I guess I misunderstood the question ^^

Comment: Let me explain: I cloned my Repo to my VPS, but now I need to know if the local HEAD is the same like the remote one. 
If there was a commit on the remote branch, the HEAD is different.

I tried git diff xyzscript https://github.com/user/xyzscript/master, but im getting: "error: Could not access 'xyz"

Comment: That clarifies things a little bit, but I'm still unclear on the problem. Can you update your question to show specifically what commands you are running and what the errors are? In your comment there, it's not clear to what `xyz` refers.

Comment: @patrick I'm not sure if you misunderstood the question or if I did :)

Comment: Now I'm more confused! You initially asked about "getting the short HEAD of a remote branch", but now you're running `git diff`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited the Question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if your local branch differs from the associated remote tracking branch (assuming you are on the `master` branch):

```
git remote update
if ! git diff --quiet origin/master; then
    echo "the branch is different!"
fi
```

You could also write instead:

```
git diff --quiet @{u}
```

Where `@{u}` refers to the remote tracking branch, so this would work for any local branch that is tracking a remote branch.

Comment: Thank you so much, that check does work for me!

I'm gonna edit my question with your code snippet, if it's okay for you? :)

Comment: If this solved your issue, then the thing to do is to mark this as the accepted answer by checking the checkmark next to the answer.  There's no need to update your question.

Answer (score 2):

Run `rev-parse` on the local copy of the remote branch

```
git fetch
git rev-parse --short origin/master
```

Comment: Yes that's looking good!
But after trying it, I'm getting this error:
fatal: Needed a single revision